# MySQL problem when I run install.sql against new DB

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import an sql file to a new MySQL database, but get error:

> ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 65: Data truncated for column 'for_PlayerPlayerActions' at row 1

I have zero MySQL knowledge to be honest.

I've been using the url https://bitbucket.org/Maverick_of_UC/hlstatsx-community-edition/wiki/Install which allows to me to run a stats site for a gaming server.  I had it all running on a Windows 2003 (MySQL & IIS) server for years, but have rebuilt the server on Windows 2012R2 and I can't run the install.sql file against the database called hlstatsx.

Log into MySQL

```
mysql> create database hlstatsx;
```

Then in a command prompt:

```
C:\hlstatsx\sql>mysql -uroot -p hlstatsx < install.sql
Enter password: *********
ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 65: Data truncated for column 
'for_PlayerPlayerActions' at row 1
```

if I open install.sql in Notepad++:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hlstats_Actions` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`game` varchar(32) NOT NULL default 'valve',
`code` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`reward_player` int(11) NOT NULL default '10',
`reward_team` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`team` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`description` varchar(128) default NULL,
`for_PlayerActions` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`for_PlayerPlayerActions` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`for_TeamActions` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`for_WorldActions` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `gamecode` (`code`,`game`,`team`),
KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hlstats_Actions`
--
```

and go to line 65 I see:

```
INSERT INTO `hlstats_Actions` (`game`, `code`, `reward_player`, `reward_team`, `team`, `description`, `for_PlayerActions`, `for_PlayerPlayerActions`, `for_TeamActions`, `for_WorldActions`) VALUES
('tf', 'flagevent_defended', 1, 0, '', 'Defended the flag', '1', '', '', ''),
('tf', 'flagevent_captured', 5, 1, '', 'Captured the flag', '1', '', '', ''),
('tf', 'flagevent_dropped', -2, 0, '', 'Dropped the flag (while alive)', '1', '', '', ''),
...
```

I got this all working years ago but took no notes, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: how is for_PlayerPlayerActions defined inthe database?  You show us the INSERT but not the CREATE TABLE that would define the column's max size ( which could have changed across mysql releases)

Comment: I've added it above, could it be something to do with the charset?

Comment: I don't see any reason to implicate charset.  The column is an ENUM and can be 0 or 1.   what is the value of `for_PlayerPlayerActions` in your insert?

Comment: Are you able to view the install.sql file here rather that me copy parts over? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiDwztGEAbFV_DK0gpBZBhsdHMtp

Comment: An admit for this DB has just replied saying "try to create database in utf8mb4_unicode_ci / utf8mb4_general_ci collation. Then import database from sql file."  But didn't say how.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table definition:

```
`for_PlayerPlayerActions` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
```

the column definition requires a value for that column and the data for that column you are attempting to load is a null/empty string.

Notice:

```
('tf', 'flagevent_defended', 1, 0, '', 'Defended the flag', '1', '', '', ''),
```

All those '' are empty strings/NULL and thus are outside the allowable range of the enum, which must be '0' or '1'.

It looks like you actually have a number of columns with the same problem.  You can get around this problem in loading these, to remove the NOT NULL definition for the columns and rerun your sql script.

Afterwards, update all the NULL values for the columns in this table to 0 and then change the structure back and you should be fine with any dumps and loads in the future.

This likely occurred because NULLs were allowed for these columns at some point, or the table definition was added after rows existed prior to those columns being added.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not an SQL chap so I think you are saying I need to edit the file and remove NOT NULLand re-run?  The site that built this for other teams seem to have no issue running this though and my old server did.  So I'm not sure why it's just me?  I'm on MySQL 5.5 coudl it be the version?

Comment: Yes, remove the NOT NULL from those enum columns and should work.  Regardless of what other sites might have experienced, it's your data that has the issue.

Comment: I will try this.  What I mean is the install.sql is a file everyone has been using to populate this new database, it's not my data.  https://bitbucket.org/Maverick_of_UC/hlstatsx-community-edition/wiki/Install

Comment: Well, again all I can say is that it's a simple and obvious issue with the data not matching the current table definition.   Projects of all sorts have bugs and mistakes.  It's also possible that there is an upgrade path you did not strictly follow that might have fixed this data in the past.  If it was me, I would just fix it and move on since this is a one time installation.

Comment: Importing it into MySQL in Linux worked, then exported it and imported into Windows MySQL again and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you had success.  Strictly speaking, you are using terms (import, export) that aren't relevant.  If you want to help others out in the future, it would help if you were specific.  Your question showed you ran a script.  Anyone can write  a sql script and run it.  An Import involves running `mysqlimport` which is a wrapper around LOAD DATA infile and is typically used to load in csv files.  The mysqldump tool creates a .sql file, which is I guess what you meant by `export`.  If you did something else you should explain what you did.